# How can I update SF object picklist field using marketing cloud journey update object activity? is it even possible to update?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Not sure if I should be posting know how question here but still want to understand How can I update SF object picklist field using marketing cloud journey update object activity? is it even possible to update a picklist field.

I have tried passing the exact same value while associating the DE text field to the picklist field in journey update object activity but it throws soft error. not sure if there is a way around

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update a picklist field in CRM using **Object Activity**

Illustrated below, [updating Title of a Contact record]
[image]

Note: That you need to have a valid 18digit ID of the object you wish to update.
Which the pick list value resides.

More info: [Offical doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_update_object_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi Vishal, so my issue is different, i have a form which injects into DE. Col 1 (text) which gets the values through form needs to be synchronized with Lead object field (picklist) the values are same but I am not selecting the drop down, instead providing link to the entry source DE form Marketing cloud attributes section.

Comment: I am still NOT clear on your requirement....... does this help? [UpdateSinglesaleSforceobject](https://ampscript.guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject/)

Comment: In short NO, the answer above does not help as my problem is slightly different. Let me rephrase, is it possible to pass values collected into DE, to a filed within SF which is of type picklist?

Comment: Thanks @pragyanshukukreti for rephrasing.... as per my knowledge.. there are only two ways of sending data from `SFMC -> CRM` .... 1. using Object Activity   2. using UpdateSinglesaleSforceobject AMPscript function... lets see if any other SFMC dev come up with a diff approach.